# issues getting events data using facebook graph api v2.5

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello i'm trying to get some event information using the facebook graph api v2.5 but I keep getting the error message facebook.GraphAPIError: Unknown path components: /144259682284406. It works without the fields when I don't specify v2.5 however I need to use v2.5 to get the necessary fields

> /v2.5/144259682284406?fields=events{name,id,timezone,start_time,end_time,picture,description,category,type,attending_count,interested_count,declined_count}
>   Blockquote

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking; the exact same request [works fine in Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=144259682284406%3Ffields%3Devents%7Bname%2Cid%2Ctimezone%2Cstart_time%2Cend_time%2Cpicture%2Cdescription%2Ccategory%2Ctype%2Cattending_count%2Cinterested_count%2Cdeclined_count%7D&version=v2.5)

Comment: And so does https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/144259682284406?fields=events%7Bname%2Cid%2Ctimezone%2Cstart_time%2Cend_time%2Cpicture%2Cdescription%2Ccategory%2Ctype%2Cattending_count%2Cinterested_count%2Cdeclined_count%7D&access_token=… when called directly in the browser.

Comment: @CBroe  I'm using python and calling the  graph.get_object method.       Python code: " searchstring = ("/v2.5/144259682284406?fields=events{name,id,timezone,start_time,end_time,picture,description,categor‌​y,type,attending_count,interested_count,declined_count}")                 post = graph.get_object(searchstring)"

Comment: And which SDK/framework is that …?

Comment: Is it this one, http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html? In that case, you shouldn’t pass the API version that way, but simply specify it when creating the `facebook.GraphAPI` object instance, as shown in the very first example.

Comment: Hey @CBroe cheers, that worked a treat. I was passing it the wrong way, here's the correct way: graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='your_token', version='2.2')

Comment: Great! I’ve added a short answer summarizing our findings.

Answer (score 0):

The exact same request worked in Graph API Explorer or when calling the API via URL directly – so it must have been something in how you pass the parameter in your SDK code.

Checking http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html it turns out, that the API version has to be passed when the `facebook.GraphAPI` object instance is created,

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='your_token', version='2.2')
```

That way the SDK will take care of putting that version string into the URLs that the API requests are made to by itself, so that you don’t have to take care of that any more in the following code where you make the API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

The id `144259682284406` you are using is a page object and if you want to get page events you should query like this:

`page/events/?fields=field1,field2,...` in your case:

> /v2.5/144259682284406/events/?fields=name,id,timezone,start_time,end_time,picture,description,category,type,attending_count,interested_count,declined_count